# IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet) Transcription with Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, linguistics

I'm looking into designing a software platform that will aid linguists and anthropologists in their study of previously unstudied languages. Statistics show that around 1,000 languages exist that have never been studied by a person outside of their respective speaker groups.

My goal is to utilize TensorFlow to make a platform that will allow linguists to study and document these languages more efficiently, and to help them create written systems for the ones that don't have a written system already. One of their current methods of accomplishing such a task is three-fold: 1) Record a native speaker conversing in the language, 2) Listening to that recording and trying to transcribe it into the IPA, 3) From the phonetics, analyzing the phonemics and phonotactics of the language to eventually create a written system for the speaker.

My proposed platform would cut that research time down from a minimum of a year to a maximum of six months. Before I start, I have some questions...

**What would be required to train TensorFlow to transcribe live audio into the IPA? Has this already been done? and if so, how would I utilize a previous solution for this project? Is a project like this even possible with TensorFlow? if not, what would you recommend using instead?**

My apologies for the magnitude of this question. I don't have much experience in the realm of machine learning, as I am just beginning the research process for this project. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you talked to a linguist about this? Phoneme recognition can be much more difficult than recognizing words https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/phonemerecognition/

Comment: @Aaron technically, it's *phones* here, not phonemes, but not sure if it makes it any better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I will take a first shot at answering this. Since the question is pretty general, my answer will have to be pretty general as well.

1. What would be required. At the very least you would have to have a large dataset of pre-transcribed data. Ideally a large amount of spoken language audio mapped to characters in the phonetic alphabet, so the system could learn the sound of individual characters rather than whole transcribed words. If such a dataset doesn't exist, a less granular dataset could be used, mapping single words to their transcriptions. Then you would need a model, that is the actual neural network architecture implemented in code. And lastly you would need some computing resources. This is not something you can train casually, you would either have to buy some time in a cloud based machine learning framework (like Google Cloud ML) or build a fairly expensive machine to train at home.
2. Has this been done? I don't know. I don't think so. There have been published papers reporting various degrees of success at training systems to transcribe speech. Here is one, for example, http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/lexfree/lexfree.pdf It seems that since the alphabet you want to transcribe to is specifically designed to capture the way words sound rather than just write down the words you might have more success at training such a model.
3. Is it possible with TensorFlow. Yes, most likely. TensorFlow is well suited for implementing most modern deep learning architectures. Unless you end up designing some really weird and very original model for this purpose, TensorFlow should work just fine.

*Edit*: after some thought in part 1, you would have to use a dataset mapping spoken words to their transcriptions, since I expect that the same sound pronounced separately would be different from when the same sound is used in a word.

Answer (score 2):

This has actually been done, albeit in PyTorch, by a group at CMU: https://github.com/xinjli/allosaurus